# how to fetch correct PhoneSignalStrength in WM 6.5 C#

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I am using **SystemState.phonesignalStrength** property to fetch signal strength in my **Windows Mobile Application 6.5(C#) for HTC HD 8585**,

Problem With this property is that it always gives 100 value as signalstrength even if there is no sim in phone or phone is in Airplane Mode.
I my very confused what is happening.

Any Idea ,How Can i use it to fetch correct signal strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can P/Invoke the RIL API function [RIL_GetSignalQuality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919482).

Alternatively, you can P/Invoke the [State and Notification Broker API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488580%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) and monitor the SN_PHONESIGNALSTRENGTH* registry key defined in snapi.h.

I don't believe Microsoft provides access to either of these things through the Compact Framework, but there may be 3rd party libraries that do the P/Invoking for you. [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) is a good place to start.

Both of these things are, however, OEM support dependent. (Microsoft provides the interface, the OEM must implement it.)